# Amazon S3 bucket policy to restrict IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created bucket policy below, but I can't access any images from server I set up the other day(got 403). How can I allow specific IP address in the condition?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1527266936788",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt11111111,
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx/*",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx/24"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: That policy is correct and matches the docs for AWS. Are you sure the server you are requesting from falls in that CIDR block?

Comment: ...and is the address block a valid CIDR block )on a valid bit boundary)?  a `/24` block, by definition, ends with `.0` as the last octet.

Comment: You might consider temporarily removing the condition to confirm that everything else is working correctly. If so, then you know that it is merely the IP range that is causing an issue.

Comment: I can access images from my server, if I removed the condition. Could anyone explain step by step how to set IP in the condition including command, how to find correct IP...

Comment: @Ken if this is a server on AWS why not look at an Instance Role instead of a bucket policy?